# How to make multiple REST calls asynchronous in python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have the following code to make multiple REST calls. Basically I have a dictionary where key is a string and value is a JSON date that I need to use as payload to pass to a REST API POST method.

At the moment, the dictionary contains 10 entries, so I need to make 10 REST calls.

At the moment, I have implemented using requests package in python3 which is synchronous in nature. So after 1 REST call, it waits for its response and similarly for 10 REST calls, it will wait 10 times for the response from API.

```
def createCategories(BACKEND_URL, token, category):
    url = os.path.join(BACKEND_URL, 'api/v1/category-creation')

    category_dict = read_payloads(category)

    headers = {
        "token": f'{token}',
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "accept": "application/json"
    }

    for name, category_payload in category_dict.items():
        json_payload = json.dumps(category_payload)
        response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=json_payload)
        ##########################
        ## Load as string and parsing
        response_data = json.loads(response.text)
        print(response_data)

        category_id = response_data['id']
        message = 'The entity with id: ' + str(category_id) + ' is created successfully. '
        logging.info(message)

    return "categories created successfully."
```

I read that we need to use asyncio to make these asynchronous. What code changes do I need to make?

Answer (score 2):

You can continue using `requests` library. You need to use `threading` or `concurrent.futures` modules to make several requests simutaneoudly.

Another option is to use some `async` library like `aiohttp` or some others.

```py
import requests

from threading import current_thread
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, Future
from time import sleep, monotonic

URL = "https://api.github.com/events"


def make_request(url: str) -> int:
    r = requests.get(url)
    sleep(2.0)  # wait n seconds
    return r.status_code


def done_callback(fut: Future):
    if fut.exception():
        res = fut.exception()
        print(f"{current_thread().name}. Error: {res}")
    elif fut.cancelled():
        print(f"Task was canceled")
    else:
        print(f"{current_thread().name}. Result: {fut.result()}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    urls = [URL for i in range(20)]  # 20 tasks

    start = monotonic()

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(5) as pool:
        for i in urls:
            future_obj = pool.submit(make_request, i)
            future_obj.add_done_callback(done_callback)

    print(f"Time passed: {monotonic() - start}")
```