# Future does not complete

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I am working on creating a `asyncio.Future` callback for requests whereby I store the body of the response in `json` format and return this result. I initially wanted to create a callback on the function `on_response`, however I was not certain how to implement this. Therefore, I decided to include option parameters to add into the callable such as `url`.

For example:

```
import asyncio
from functools import partial as func
import requests
import json

url = "https://www.scrapethissite.com/pages/ajax-javascript/?ajax=true&year=2015"

class schedulerLoop(asyncio.Future):
    def __init__(self, url):
        super(schedulerLoop, self).__init__()
        self._url = url
    
    @staticmethod
    def unwrapper(funct):
        return funct()

    def _future(self, *args):
        return self.add_done_callback(func(self.unwrapper, *args))

    async def on_response(self):
        if self.done():
            obj = await self._future(func(requests.get, self._url))
            body = json.loads(obj)
            return body
        else:
            self.exception()

async def main(loop):
    await loop.on_response()

loop = schedulerLoop(url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main(loop))
```

I find that I get:

> asyncio.exceptions.InvalidStateError: Exception is not set.

Which supposes that `on_response` the `Future` is not `done`, and so we get a `False` result but there seems be no no `Exception` neither.

Comment: `requests` is a sync library you should not use use with `asyncio`.  In addition `add_done_callback` does not return anything. What do you want to achieve with the code? Do you want to do simultaneous request to API or you have any other need?

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev Thank you for looking into my question. I originally wanted something that would callback into the function so ```self.add_done_callback(func(self.unwrapper, callback = self.on_response))``` then have `def on_response` to contain the result of the request. This I probably would have needed an extra function to add the callable, but then again it turned out complex as I was only adding values to the callable. Essentially, in my line of code, I wanted to send a bunch of request to a number of urls and return their json.

Comment: I recently answered very similar question, check it please and let me know if it solves your  issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73721364/10311377

Comment: @ArtiomKozyrev You approach is very interesting and I have read that `concurrent.futures.Future` is largely similar to ``asyncio.Future`` except for a few functionalities. I believe that I can use your answer as a template to interpret what I am aiming for - I am still learning as I've only recently been reading to docs.

Comment: It is not similar under the hood, `concurrent.Futures` are actually wrapper around `threading` module, so there are many threads. Use `ThreadPoolExecuter` with `sync` libs like `requests`. Use `asyncio` with async libs like `aiohttp`. async model works only in one thread.